# Continuous, convex function on a normed vector space, bounded below by a linear functional plus a constant

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm studying for an exam and was looking for some good questions in some outside textbooks.  I found this problem in Ciarlet's functional textbook:

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex and continuous function.  Show that there exists $l \in X'$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) > l(x) + c$ for all $x \in X$

My thoughts: Drawing a quick sketch, the intuition for why this is true is clear.  My idea was to consider $A := \text{im}(f)$, and define $M := \{tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) : x,y \in X \text{ and } t \in [0,1]\}$ and try to apply Hahn-Banach Separation theorem, but there are two problems with this: (1) we cannot guarantee the openness or closedness of $M$ and (2) using HB here would give us a separating hyperplane defined by a linear functional whose domain is in $\mathbb{R}$.  So this leaves me with trying to be clever by choosing some particular sets in $X$ to separate (e.g. I tried looking at level sets of $f$), but I haven't been able to make much progress.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Consider that the epigraph $\text{epi}(f)$ is a closed convex set in $X\times \mathbb{R}$. Choose any $\epsilon > 0$ and use the Hahn-Banach separation theorem on $\text{epi}(f)$ and the compact set $\{(x, f(x)-\epsilon)\}$ for any $x\in X$.

Comment: Oh, I see, so I needed to consider the graph rather than just dealing with $M$.  Thank you!

Comment: epi($f$) is closed convex. $\{(x,f(x)-\epsilon)\}$ is compact. And then the separation theorem is applicable. But how is that related to what you want to prove?