# How to prove that continuous convex functional on normed vector space must be lower bounded by some continuous affine functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-geometry, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Let $f:X\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous convex function. How to show that there exists a continuous linear functional $l$ and a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>l(x)+c$  holds for all $x\in X$? I think it could be proved by hyperplane separation theorem. But I don't know how to start it.

Comment: The comments at this similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2734823/42969 may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The epigraph $\operatorname{epi}f$ is closed and convex set in $X\times\Bbb R$ and $(x,f(x)-\epsilon)\not\in\operatorname{epi}f$ is compact for any $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in X$. By the separation theorem there exists a non-zero $(\phi,\psi)\in(X\times\Bbb R)'=X'\times\Bbb R$ such that the hyperplane $(\phi,\psi)\cdot(x,y)=\phi(x)+\psi y=\alpha$ separates $\operatorname{epi}f$ and the point. We can choose the sign such that $\operatorname{epi}f$ belongs to the half-space $\phi(x)+\psi y>\alpha$. Clearly $\psi\ne 0$ since $\phi(x)>\alpha$ is not possible for all $x\in X$ and $\phi\ne 0$. Hence, $\psi>0$ otherwise $y\to+\infty$ (still in $\operatorname{epi}f$) will give us a contradiction with $\phi(x)+\psi y>\alpha$. Finally $(x,f(x))\in\operatorname{epi}f$ then $\phi(x)+\psi f(x)>\alpha$. Divide by $\psi$ and move the things around.

Comment: thanks. I never thought dual of product space has such a precise form.

Comment: @A.$\Gamma$. Do you know how this result implies, that if $f, g$ are convex continuous functions, with $g \leq f$, then there exists an affine continuous function $h$ with $g \leq h \leq f$?

Comment: @h3fr43nd It is not true. Take e.g. $f(x)=g(x)=x^2$. There is no space for an affine function in between. However, if $g$ is concave instead then it is the standard result on separation for convex sets. Another related reference: Fenchel duality.

Comment: @h3fr43nd I do not have any reference at hand. Just prove that for a continuous function $f$ the strict epigraph is open. Now apply the [separation theorem II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem#Statements_and_proof). Finally, comment on the graph of $f$ as boundary points giving non-strict inequality.